# Lualatex: using verbatimtex in metapost

Tags: luatex, metapost

I want to use `verbatimtex` in `metapost` and compile it in `lualatex`. Followed is a small code. But it failed. I have googled and added `verbatimtex` block here and there but no lucky. Please help. Thank you.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
etex

\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1);
z0 = (0,0); z1 = (sqrt(3)*cm,0);
z2 = (sqrt(3)*cm,1cm);
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
label.bot(btex $\sqrt{3}$ etex, 1/2[z0,z1]);
label.rt(btex $\frac{1}{2}$ etex, 1/2[z1,z2]);
label.top(btex 1 etex, 1/2[z0,z2]);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

verbatimtex
\end{document}
etex
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MetaPost is already integrated in Lua(La)TeX, so in most cases, `verbatimtex… etex` is useless. You might want to use it though if you want your pictures centered, flushed left or right and so on, to insert before each picture the `\leavevmode` command necessary to do that.

See below, and the `luamplib` [documentation](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf) for more details, especially page 2.

```
%\RequirePackage{luatex85} % Needed mostly for the standalone class
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    %\mplibtextextlabel{enable} % Not needed here since you use btex… etex
    \everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex; beginfig(1);}
    \everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
Here is a picture:
\begin{center}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    z0 = (0,0); z1 = (sqrt(3)*cm,0);
    z2 = (sqrt(3)*cm,1cm);
    draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
    label.bot(btex $\sqrt{3}$ etex, 1/2[z0,z1]);
    label.rt(btex $\frac{1}{2}$ etex, 1/2[z1,z2]);
    label.top(btex 1 etex, 1/2[z0,z2]);
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Franck. To be honest, I have read the luamplib  documentation before I asked this question. But due to my English ability and not familiar to lualatex, I was lost. Thanks again.